# “Unrecognised Dataset” error occurs in altair chart for multiuser

Tags: pandas, streamlit, altair, multi-user

**Summary**
I have developed an app to plot the values in a altair chart. The values are first appended in the pandas dataframe and then plotted using the altair chart. The app works fine in the single-user case. In the multi user case, app throws the Unrecognised dataset error in the plotting area.

**Steps to reproduce**
Import the necessary libraries
Declare the pandas dataframe
Declare the data to be plotted
Append the data one by one in the dataframe
Plot the data using altair chart

**Code Snippet**
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import altair as alt
import time as t
import math
st.title("Sine wave Plotting")
df_Tidal_Volume = pd.DataFrame(columns=["time","Tidal_Volume"])
chart_Tidal_Volume = st.empty()
start_time = datetime.now()
while True:
try:
data = [5*math.sin(math.radians(0)),5*math.sin(math.radians(9)),5*math.sin(math.radians(13.5)),5*math.sin(math.radians(18)),5*math.sin(math.radians(22.5)),5*math.sin(math.radians(27)),5*math.sin(math.radians(31.5)),5*math.sin(math.radians(36)),5*math.sin(math.radians(40.5)),5*math.sin(math.radians(45))]
t.sleep(0.03)
time = datetime.now()
df_Tidal_Volume = df_Tidal_Volume.append({"time": time, "Tidal_Volume": data[0]}, ignore_index=True)
latest_time = time - start_time
if latest_time >= timedelta(milliseconds=50):
a=chart_Tidal_Volume.altair_chart(alt.Chart(df_Tidal_Volume.tail(200)).mark_line().encode(x='time',y=alt.Y('Tidal_Volume', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0,6]))))
print("Plot Success")
else:
print("Data not received")
t.sleep(0.03)

**Expected behavior:**
The app should plot the data while accessing the app from multiple devices

**Actual behavior:**
The app throws the following error while accessing from more than one device
[Error from Streamlit Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U8Px.png)

**Links**
Link to your GitHub repo:appdevelopment/st1.py at main · santhosh-graceson/appdevelopment · GitHub
Link to your deployed app:https://abcd1234.streamlit.app/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.